# Number of unique elements only using equality comparisons

Tags: algorithm, performance, time-complexity, unique, equality

Is there a way to find the number of unique elements in a list in faster (worst case) running time than O(n^2) if you can only use equality comparisons between two elements? No deleting, copying or other indexing of elements is allowed (other than looping through them to compare). We basically don't know what the values of the elements are, we can only tell if two of them are the same. There is no more information about the distribution of elements and you can't assume integers only.

The best I could do is just brute force it - comparing the current element to all the previous elements which is O(n^2) but I'm not sure how to prove that this is the best possible running time.

Comment: Only equality is very limiting. It really doesn't make sense to me that you could do any better than n^2. The algorithm is too blind to the data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If a list contains N elements with only one duplicate, then there are N(N-1)/2 possible pairs of elements that can be compared for equality, and only one of those pairs will compare equal.

So, given any algorithm that is purported to count distinct elements, and adversary can provide it with a list of N distinct elements and observe which comparisons it makes and what answer it provides.  Then:

- If the algorithm gives an answer that is not N, then it's wrong.
- Otherwise, if the algorithm makes fewer than N(N-1)/2 comparisons, then there is at least one pair that it didn't compare.  The adversary can set those two elements equal and run the algoirthm again.  Since all the comparisons it makes will have the same result, it will give the answer N again, but this time it will be wrong.

So any algorithm that always makes fewer than N(N-1)/2 comparisons must return the wrong answer for at least one input.